# Is "reeducate" correct?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a correct expression for an activity when a person is injured or in a bad leath condition for any reason and is doing special exercises to feel better. Is it reeducate? Rehabilitate? Vindicate? Thank you.

Comment: *Rehabilitate* seems to me the word you need. For recovery a person may be looking for a *rehabilitative* and *restorative* programme.

Comment: Hello, Jana. This would be a better question if you added dictionary definitions for your suggestions, and the examples of usage they provide {eg those at [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rehabilitate)}.

Comment: One does need to be a hair wary of "reeducate", as that term has been used in several Communist countries to mean being sent to a sort of "reform school" for people who question the regime.  Thus it can carry bad connotations in some circles.  Similarly, "rehabilitate" is associated with treatment for addiction.  Not that these words shouldn't be used, but be careful to not accidentally raise the wrong connotation.

Answer (score 3):

Of the words you've given "rehabilitate" is the best. However, rehabilitate has the connotation of recovery from drug use.

I would offer up "Physical therapy" as an alternative. E.g. "After my surgery I needed to do physical therapy on my shoulder for six months."

"re-learn" or "re-educate" could be used in an informal context, "I need to re-learn how to use my left arm."

"Vindicate" should not be used, as it means something else.

Comment: Re-educate also has the connotation of being forced to change your opinion about something against your will.

Answer (score 0):

Rehabilitate is a word widely used in the medical profession for what you're describing.